# Where can I find Mono.NET binaries for Solaris?

Tags: c#, mono

On below page it is mentioned that package for Solaris will be available on download page but I don't see anything here. Am I looking at wrong place or link is broken??

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/solaris/

http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin

Thanks,
Omkar

Comment: Solaris is not Linux. Meanwhile, you can always build from source code if no binary can be found.